# angularjs date time sorting not working properly on table

Tags: angularjs, sorting, filter

I have the sample data set (below) from my backend and I am passing it into an angularjs table. When I sort the date column, it is taking the formatted (by using date filter) date string for sorting instead of taking the real long date to sort.

**JSON Data**

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("57e21d452679a426808caa09"),
    "name": "John",
    "createdOn": NumberLong(1474436421360)
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Created Time</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
            <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ user.createdOn | date : 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm' : timezone }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any sorting code here,can you post your whole code or a plunker ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement sorting

Check the below example.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('DefaultController', DefaultController);

function DefaultController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.users = [
    { id: 1, name: 'John', date: 1474436481360 },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dale', date: 1444936421360 },
    { id: 3, name: 'Torres', date: 1464445481360 }
  ];
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

th:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

th, td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-click="ctrl.sortBy = 'name'; ctrl.sortOrder = !ctrl.sortOrder">Name</th>
          <th ng-click="ctrl.sortBy = 'date'; ctrl.sortOrder = !ctrl.sortOrder">Created On</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="user in ctrl.users | orderBy: ctrl.sortBy : ctrl.sortOrder">
          <td ng-bind="user.name"></td>
          <td ng-bind="user.date | date : 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @Abdul, thx I've tried out, its not working out for the below data, with and without seconds (:ss) on table.

{ first : "super", last : "admin", inTime : NumberLong(1474378756750)},
{ first : "micha", last : "robin", inTime : NumberLong(1474378816201)},
{ first : "super", last : "admin", inTime : NumberLong(1474378839686)},
{ first : "micha", last : "robin", inTime : NumberLong(1474378923251)},
{ first : "super", last : "admin", inTime : NumberLong(1474378955719)},
{ first : "micha", last : "robin", inTime : NumberLong(1474537956418)},
{ , inTime : NumberLong(1474537978301)}

Comment: Is the NumberLong() function from MongoDB?, just to verify could you remove it and check whether it works